# Eu fui fazer um jogo no unity e deu o erro NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]O código é esse:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyAttack : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float timeBetweenAttacks = 0.5f;
    public int attackDamage = 10;


    Animator anim;
    GameObject player;
    PlayerHealth playerHealth;
    //EnemyHealth enemyHealth;
    bool playerInRange;
    float timer;


    void Awake ()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");
        playerHealth = player.GetComponent <PlayerHealth> ();
        //enemyHealth = GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();
        anim = GetComponent <Animator> ();
    }


    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject == player)
        {
            playerInRange = true;
        }
    }


    void OnTriggerExit (Collider other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject == player)
        {
            playerInRange = false;
        }
    }


    void Update ()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if(timer >= timeBetweenAttacks && playerInRange/* && enemyHealth.currentHealth > 0*/)
        {
            Attack ();
        }

        if(playerHealth.currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            anim.SetTrigger ("PlayerDead");
        }
    }


    void Attack ()
    {
        timer = 0f;

        if(playerHealth.currentHealth > 0)
        {
            playerHealth.TakeDamage (attackDamage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Onde deu o erro? Dê detalhes. Normalmente este erro ocorre por um problema originado em outro lugar ou você não tratou uma situação que era certo que poderia ter um objeto com valor `null`. Se você não está sabendo fazer isto, vai ter enorme dificuldade de lidar com outros aspectos do código.

Comment: Na linha 54  if(playerHealth.currentHealth > 0)

Comment: Ainda bem que você postou o conteúdo, porque também não temos o número da linha. Você chamou o método `Awake()` antes de executar o `Attack()`? é neste método que o campo `playerHealth` está sendo inicializado. Sem sua inicialização, vai dar esse erro mesmo. De qualquer forma, parece que esta classe está com problemas de *design* em geral. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101

Comment: Não, é o oposto. Inclusive pelos nomes, faz sentido que primeiro acorde e depois ataque.

Comment: Entao o que eu faço?

Comment: @bigown O método `Awake()` é chamado automaticamente pelo Unity-3d após o objeto ser criado, sempre antes do `Update()`. O design não é dos melhores, mas este design é a forma que é imposta pelo Unity-3d e é o design padrão do Unity-3d.

Comment: @VictorStafusa bom saber, pelo jeito não está sendo chamado ou algum erro que passa batido está ocorrendo nesta chamada.

Comment: Eu inverti a posição do codigo mas nao adiantou olha

Comment: Uma perguntinha bem simples: Tem certeza que você colocou um objeto do tipo `PlayerHealth` no seu player? Se sim, poderia postar um print do Inspector com isso?

Comment: file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/Capturar.PNG

Comment: è como q passa o print pelo comentario

Comment: tenho certeza só nao sei mandar o print eu sou novo aqui

Comment: @DanielCorreaSantos Edite a pergunta é inclua o primo lá (tem um botão pra isso no editor).

Comment: Está desenvolvendo em 2D ou 3D?

Comment: Se está dando esse erro nessa linha, é porque a variável `playerHealth` está nula. E isso se deve à chamada `playerHealth = player.GetComponent <PlayerHealth> ();` falhar. A única conclusão é o que o colega @VictorStafusa já mencionou: você não adicionou o objeto desse tipo ao objeto do jogador (o com a tag "Player").

Comment: unity3d @MeuChapeu